# Find $o\left (\frac{G}{Z (G)}\right) $

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G :=\{a^k, a^k.b|0\le k\lt 9\} $ s..t $o(a)=9$ and $o(b)=2$ and $ba= a^{-1}b.$ If $Z(G)$ denotes center of group $G,$ find the order of $G/Z(G).$

In book answer is $18.$

Comment: 19 days a member, 34 questions asked (!!) =  time to learn how to properly write mathematics in this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: Can you see what the order of $G$ is? So what do you need to show the order of the center to be?

Comment: Are you familiar with Dihedral groups? $|D_n|=2n$ and it has trivial center when $n$ is odd.

Comment: This is the Dihedral group of order $18.$ $ Z(G)$ is trivial.

Comment: I can only see that G is being generated by {a, b}.@krish how did u find order of G. It seems u multiplied 9 and 2 why?

Comment: Do you understand how the group is defined? Just write down the elements.

Comment: @Foggy: The group you wrote is actually the Dihedral group and $a,b$ are standard generators. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I split this into many parts for you. The order of the parts is such that later parts may depend on earlier ones.

1. Show that $a^k=a^\ell$, if and only if $k\equiv\ell\pmod9$. Review what you know about cyclic groups, if this is not crystal clear.
2. Show by induction that for all natural numbers $k$ the equation
   $$
   ba^k=a^{-k}b
   $$
   holds in the group $G$.
3. Show that the element $a^k$ commutes with $b$ if and only if $a^k=a^{-k}$.
4. Show that $2k\equiv0\pmod9$ if and only if $k\equiv0\pmod9$. Review what you know about congruences, if this is not crystal clear.
5. Show that the element $a^k$ is in the center if and only if $a^k=1$.
6. Show that the element $ba^k$ commutes with $b$ if and only if $a^k=1$.
7. Show that the element $b$ does not commute with the element $a$. Conclude that $Z(G)$ is trivial.

Comment: +1 It's beyond my ability to divide the problem in such a small parts. This is really amazing. I could use it later (may be elsewhere). Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Every non-identity element of $G$ is of the form $a^k$ or $a^kb, 0 \leq k \leq 8.$ Try to show that none of these elements can be in the center. For example, if $a^k \in Z(G)$ then $a^kb=ba^k.$ On the other hand by the given condition, $a^kb=ba^{-k}.$ So we must have $a^k=a^{-k} \Rightarrow a^{2k}=1 \Rightarrow 2k|9.$

Comment: +1 These are the key ideas. Sorry about getting in the way of your attempt to make the OP think about it a bit harder.